# MySQL connection using my hostname instead of ipv4 address, leading to no access

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I recently began a new internship where we use the Laravel PHP framework. When trying to connect to the company's MySQL server, I can connect using the given credentials using a program such as MySQL Workbench because my ipv4 address is whitelisted. When using Laravel, it is using my hostname in the connection string, leading to a no access error and I am not sure how to change that. Does anyone know how to fix this?

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'xxxx'@'ipxx-xx-xx-xxx.ri.ri.cox.net' (using password: YES)
```

Comment: Can we see your database.php configuration file

Comment: @DiegoPonciano it is just the default database.php from Laravel. https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/config/database.php
All database credentials are provided in the .env

Comment: Confirm your .env has the correct host, then `php artisan config:clear`

Comment: the OP is talking about their address, not the address of the host they are connecting to, but the address they are coming from

Answer (score -2):

I had the same issue, my mistake was incorrect username defined for local development vs remote connection, after correcting it, mysql connection picks the ip instead of my hostname. Also the following configuration fix the issue too. original answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71168407/couldnt-change-db-host-to-spesific-ip-or-another-hostname-laravel)

```
DATABASE_URL=mysql://username:password@db_host:3306/db_name
```

Add this to your env variables

Comment: This question is not about Laravel config at all, it's a configuration issue on the MySQL database.

Comment: It's about Laravel configuration. Laravel MySQL driver picks the hostname instead of ip (this ip whitelisted in the MySQL but the hostname not) and use that hostname in MySQL connection.

Comment: The database does not care and cannot tell whether you connect via hostname or IP address. The error means the IP address is not whitelisted. That it does a reverse lookup on the IP to display the message is irrelevant.

Comment: @miken32 yes db doesn't care about the incoming connection request, and exactly the error means what you mentioned, but if you see the "When using Laravel,it is using my hostname in the connection string,leading to a no access error and I am not sure how to change that."in the original question,it says obviously in the Laravel project it cannot connect to db which in my case because of wrong username the Laravel MySQL driver select hostname ('username'@'blah-blah-blah-blah-xx-xx-xx-xx.dsl.bell.ca') instead of ip ('username'@'xx.xx.xx.xx'). idk why it behaves this way but the said config fix it