# Couldn't change DB_HOST to spesific IP or another hostname Laravel

Tags: laravel

Hello I need to change DB_HOST from localhost to another IP or hostname on Laravel.
I have change my .env to:

```php
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=192.168.1.55
DB_SOCKET=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=testdb
DB_USERNAME=userdb
DB_PASSWORD=12345
```

I also change config/database.php to:

```php
'mysql' => [
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
    'host' => env('DB_HOST', '192.168.1.55'),
    'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
    'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'testdb'),
    'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'userdb'),
    'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', '12345'),
    'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'),
    'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
    'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    'prefix' => '',
    'prefix_indexes' => true,
    'strict' => true,
    'engine' => null,
    'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
    ]) : [],
],
```

I have execute command:

```sh
php artisan config:clear
php artisan optimize:clear
```

I try to migrate but the app still apointing to localhost, not to host I already set to IP, here is the error:

```php
Illuminate\Database\QueryException
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'userdb'@'localhost' (using password: YES)...
```

Comment: have you try to connect this database other way like work bench or php ? 
you have done all ok check your user name and password again

Comment: `Access denied for user`  means you something wrong with user name password before use in laravel make sure try with `mysql workbench` or any GUI tool

Comment: I have made sure that I can connect using standard akses, using terminal etc, the problem is app is pointing to localhost userdb'@'localhost not to IP that I have setup on .env and database.php configuration.

Comment: Anything to do with DB_SOCKET/unix_socket? If you are using socket then why is this IP for? Anyway everything seems good to me except that socket part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's only solved by using DATABASE_URL not standard ENV, I don't know why?:

```php
DATABASE_URL=mysql://userdb:12345@dbserver:3306/testdb
```

and still being a mystery.